# How to use scope of a model, in a different model's controller in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2, scope

i got 2 models. Segmentation and Campaign models.

Campaign has_many segmentations and Segmentation belongs_to Campaign.

I take inputs from user and create a specific user Lists based on the given filter inputs and i save these inputs in my database.

and this is what i save in my db

```
  t.string   :segmentation_name
  t.integer  :date_range
  t.string   :first_event ,              null: false
  t.integer  :first_event_count
  t.string   :second_event
  t.integer  :second_event_count
  t.boolean  :did_the_event
  t.integer  :user_count
```

after getting all these inputs

i did all these where queries to funnel the segment

```
time=Time.now - params[:segmentation][:date_range].to_i.days #date range basi
         currentTime=Time.now 
 if params[:segmentation][:first_event_count].blank? 

 @segmentedUsers=Event.where(params[:segmentation][:first_event] + " > 0").pluck(:user_id)
@segmentedUsers=Event.where(created_at: time .. currentTime)
  params[:segmentation][:user_count]=@segmentedUsers.count

else 

 @segmentedUsers=Event.where(params[:segmentation][:first_event] + " >" + params[:segmentation][:first_event_count] ).pluck(:user_id)  

 params[:segmentation][:user_count]=@segmentedUsers.count

end
```

but after that i want to use these segments in my campaign view and controller but after creating  a segment even tho i got my wanted users by their user_id's i don't know them in my campaign controller.

So while i was looking for a way in documentation and api i found scopes.

So basically i think i can fetch all these inputs from my db in my campaign controller and filter in my campaign controller.

But i don't know how to do it, since if i understood correctly you have to define scopes in the associative model in which case its my segmentation model, so how would I proceed to use it in my other controller?

Thanks in advance, cheers

Comment: You may want to make your question more succinct :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're a newbie, let me just give you some ideas. It **won't be a specific answer**, but it should hopefully help you out

---

**Models**

When you use `Models` in Rails, you need to ensure you appreciate the *power* of how they work.

Rails is an [MVC (Model - View - Controller)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) framework:

[image]

This means that each time you call data (through your controller), your `Model` will build an "object" that Rails can then use to output in the `view` etc.

The immediate problem you have is that is you're not using your model to construct objects - you're just using it to pull back varying pieces of data. This is bad.

--

[**Object Orientated**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming)

As Ruby is *object orientated*, it means you have to ensure that each time you call data / run controller actions, you're actually basing them around *objects*

An "object" is similar, but at the same time different, than a "variable". The main difference is that an *object* contains much more data (in JSON notation) than a variable, allowing frameworks such as Rails to process the objects in a variety of ways

The reason this is important is because when you call the following code in your controller:

```
time=Time.now - params[:segmentation][:date_range].to_i.days #date range basi
         currentTime=Time.now 
 if params[:segmentation][:first_event_count].blank? 

 @segmentedUsers=Event.where(params[:segmentation][:first_event] + " > 0").pluck(:user_id)
@segmentedUsers=Event.where(created_at: time .. currentTime)
  params[:segmentation][:user_count]=@segmentedUsers.count

else 

 @segmentedUsers=Event.where(params[:segmentation][:first_event] + " >" + params[:segmentation][:first_event_count] ).pluck(:user_id)  

 params[:segmentation][:user_count]=@segmentedUsers.count

end
```

What you're *actually* doing is attempting to build a series of *objects*. The problem is that your calls are horrible. Really bad.

You'd be better doing the following:

```
#app/models/event.rb
Class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
   scope :first_event, ->(event) { where(" #{event} > 0").pluck(:user_id) }
end

#app/controllers/events_controller.rb
Class EventsController < ApplicationController
   def your_action
       first_event = params[:segmentation][:first_event]
       @users = Event.first_event first_event
   end
end
```

This will call the respected data that you need, whilst providing a more succinct way to manage the call. And yes, I know I've skipped out a lot of your logic - it's horrible

--

**Controllers**

Finally, you want to do something very important

You want to make sure you have the correct controller setup. The problem many people have is they will typically try and make controllers to fit to their flow -- the problem here is that even if this happens, you'll not be creating your application in the most robust way.

Since Rails is object-orientated, your controllers need to match your object creation & configuration. A good rule of thumb for this will be to only create controllers for the specific objects you wish to display (in your case `segmented_users`)

Comment: Dude, you are literally my savior.Each time you answer one of my questions i learn so many things. Thank you man once again, beautiful answer.You'v been a rails master for how many years?I'v started about 2 weeks ago and can you give me some good hindsights :)

Comment: Haha thanks. I've been working with Rails for about 3 years; seriously for about 1.5. My answer really won't solve your question - you need to be more specific about what you're asking etc, but if it can provide information, it will certainly be a win-win!